# Using AzureAD secured application as a Personal App can't show login.microsoftonline.com in iFrame - does work in Developer Mode

Tags: single-sign-on, microsoft-teams

I've created a webapplication, hosted in an Azure App Service. The App Service is secured using Azure AD Authentication with *login required*.

When trying to load this page in a Personal App, the page tries to redirect to *login.microsoftonline.com* which is not able to show the page in an iFrame.

When switched to *Developer preview* the application **is** shown, passing the login using the currently signed in user.

Is there an ETA on enabling this behavior on the "non-developer preview" client?
Or is there another way to achieve this?

PS: I'm aware of the SSO javascript API, but this does require anonymous access to the application executing the JS calls. Unless I'm missing something? :)

Comment: You need to open the login popup on a separate popup as teams tab is an iframe. Currently no time line when it will be available on non-developer preview mode

Comment: I'm not able to open the popup in a window, since the authentication is handled by the Azure App Service authentication settings. In this case, "my" code is never reached...

Comment: You can do authentication for tab in teams using Azure. Could you please check these [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/authentication/auth-tab-aad) also could you please check this [sample](https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-sample-auth-node/tree/master/src/views/tab)?

Comment: Those samples work only when the code has been loaded already. I'm looking for a solution to not expose any client-side code either, through Azure App Service Authentication.

Comment: Are you looking for SSO authentication? If so Could you please check SSO sample  in the sample which i have shared?

Comment: No, I am not. I'm looking into the initial load of a Personal Tab, which is hosted in azure app service. When the app service is _configured_ with Azure AD Authentication directly on the App Service itself, the tab does not load, since there is a redirect to login.microsoftonline.com. This happens _before the App Service page itself is loaded_. In Developer Preview the scenario _does_ work.

Comment: Anything new on this one? We're at the exact same point right now. Developer Preview (and Teams Web) work fine.

Comment: Currently we don't have ETA when it will be available on non-developer preview mode

Comment: Can you elaborate on 'what' will be available in future? Like, what exactly happens in teams accessing a authenticated app service?
Is it SSO? If so, do we even need to authenticate the user with the JavaScript SDK?

Comment: I understand there is no real ETA, but can you give us at least a rough timeline? Are we talking weeks, months, quarters?